# Get function arguments values PHP

Tags: php, function

I have a function with 5 arguments and default site width variable

```
$site_width ='1000px';
function MyPrintFunction ($divName,$width=false,$html1='',$html2='', $echo = true ){
      ... plenty of code above, no need to post complete function

        $html = '<div id="'.$divName.'">';
        $html .= '</div>';
        if( $echo ){
          echo $html1.$html.$html2;
        }else{
          return $html1.$html.$html2;
        }


}
```

and than I print html like:

```
MyPrintFunction ('divname1',true);
MyPrintFunction ('divname2');
MyPrintFunction ('divname3');
```

I need to check if any of these functions has set the second argument to true, and  if yes , I need first argument name.

This way I can add the argument name to css snippet ( will be injected in head later )   and set width for it

```
#ARrument1NameSHouldGoHereAsVariable{
   width:$site_width;
}
```

I hope I explained this right. Sorry if I did not. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @L0j1k not sure I understand

Comment: If you're creating the div there, why not just put the width as the div's `style`?  It seems like that would be easier.

Comment: @G-Nugget lol , you got me  , I already have it in the function like that , and want to take it out of inline and put it where it belongs , <head>

Comment: @L0j1k check my posts first before complaining , see how many answers I got to accept

Comment: Please clarify `I need to check if any of these functions has set the second argument to true, and if yes , I need first argument name.`  It sounds like you just want to knoe the first argument, which you can't not know.

Comment: well that is what I was afraid off ,  I hoped that somehow we can find out what the first/second  argument is outside the function , you got the point , I wanted to check arguments outside the function

Comment: Then answer your own questions, or state your dissatisfaction in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noo no no, you absolutely can have optional arguments. It's a bit messy of a situation, but totally possible.

```
echo MyPrintFunction('dafsd',435);
function MyPrintFunction ($divName,$width=2342){
    return $divName . $width;
}
```

The reason it is discouraged is because...
Let's suppose you want to set a height, but not a width to 435

```
echo MyPrintFunction('dafsd',435);
function MyPrintFunction ($divName,$width=2222, $height=1111){
    return $divName . $width . $height;
}
```

Optional arguments should generally not be used, and if they are to place them at the end in an array

Please oh please let this be what you are seeking...

```
function MyPrintFunction ($divName,$width=false){
    $newObj = array();
    $newObj['divName'] = $divName;
    $newObj['width'] = $width;
    return $newObj;
}
function hasWidth($newObj) {
    if ($newObj['width']) {
        return $newObj['width'];
    }
    else {
        return 'no width!'; 
    }
}
$tempStore1 = MyPrintFunction('dafsd',123);
$tempStore2 = MyPrintFunction('dafsd');
echo hasWidth($tempStore1);
echo hasWidth($tempStore2);
```

Comment: well that is what I have but again , can someone help me if it is all possible to find out what the first and second arguments are outside the function ?

Comment: I did not post the complete function and yes I check for all arguments defined before prints , the complete function is much bigger than example above , but my question is not how my function is formulated

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: no jared , the user has option to add or NOT add the width to the div within the function , if he does , I need to find out what div name is in question so I cann add it to css that will be placed in the head . right now I have widths defined as inline style and I want to remove the from there and placed them inside the head . hope this makes sense

Comment: lol I wish it did make sense. Next suggestion! You could just return an object and then outside the function check if the width property of the returned object is true?

Comment: ok example please , im up for any solution , get array outsider or anything that I could use to attach myself to that name , basically , I need to find out OUTSIDE the function what first argument is if seond one is set at true

Comment: add an array with div name inside the function if you wish and if you can show me how to get the print outside of it

Comment: Alright Mr. @Benn Let me know if that makes sense as a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

What's this for?

```
function MyPrintFunction ($divName,$width=false,$html1='',$html2='', $echo = true ){
```

The logic goes like this

```
<?php
function blahblah($param1, $param2) {
//Put some weirdy stuff here

if($param2 == '1') {
 //Than it's true
  } else {
 //false
  }
}
blahblah("div1", "1"); //This is true
blahblah("div1", "0"); //This is false
?>
```

Comment: it is for all possible options, html before or after the main div name etc

Comment: well will do but kinda still does not gives me a clue to my question. how to get the function argument values outside of it

Comment: and if I use it the way you do I am forced to call all function arguments when printing , otherwise will have missing arguments 2 3 etc

Comment: no you cannot have missing arguments, check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php and this too http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: the answer has nothing to do with the question , I did not ask how to formulate the function

Comment: @Benn really that's why I can see why no1 is able to answer your question

Comment: I think this was clear enough , "I need to check if any of these functions has set the second argument to true, and if yes , I need first argument name." and there is no reason at all to post anything inside the function with that question ,